# List of IP protocol numbers 84 two times in list

Tags: networking, ip, network-protocols

I am referring the [List of IP protocol numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers) based on the wikipedia page but the number 84 seems appeared two times, is it a bug. I have to use this inside my javascript program.

Here is the relevant part of the list from wiki page.

```
0x52    82  SECURE-VMTP     Secure Versatile Message Transaction Protocol   RFC 1045
0x53    83  VINES   VINES   
0x54    84  TTP     TTP     
0x54    84  IPTM    Internet Protocol Traffic Manager   
0x55    85  NSFNET-IGP  NSFNET-IGP  
0x56    86  DGP     Dissimilar Gateway Protocol     
0x57    87  TCF     TCF
```

Comment: @Ramhound - these are not port numbers, but rather _protocol_ numbers. I would have thought that yes, this would be a problem.

Comment: @Ramhound These are not port numbers, they are IPv4 protocol numbers. TCP has number 6, IDP is 17, etc.

Comment: @Ramhound From the wiki page I can see it's Protocol Number not port.

Comment: I wasn't paying enough attention.  The original source of the table, IANA, doesn't even provide a valid reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I reproduce the answer given in [dslreports.com forum](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r28704884-IPv4-Protocol-84-Question-why-duplicates) by the user  `LinkLogger` :

*As to not leave an unanswered question lingering here I got in touch with the guys at Rockwell Collins and had an interesting conversation about this, but to summarize all of the computers and radios using TTP are long since gonzo but even recently (2011) IESG wanted to keep TTP and IPTM listed for 84, no doubt the result of a decision by committee, but the fact remains that TTP is deprecated and protocol 84 really only means IPTM (Internet Protocol Traffic Manager).*

Comment: To support this answer.  It was Jim Stevens who indicated the protocols for that particular protocol value.  Mr. Stevens contact information indicates he works/worked for Rockwell Collins.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close an old question/thread - I contacted Jim and IANA late Feb 2023 to get TTP/IP finally removed as it has now been deprecated since 2015. And my request was forwarded to the Internet Engineering Steering Group (IESG) that handles these matters.

**Happy to announce that as of Marts 17 - 2023**
There is now only one IP protocol under the number 84 :)
Namely `IPTM/IP` - Only took 8 years to fix!